# AWS amplify build stuck with npm ci

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, node-modules, aws-amplify

I have build an small web application with node js express with html and css which starts from the below command in npm start app.js but the same thing doesnot work in aws amplify in order to launch this as serverless application.

Here is the log for the build phase in aws amplify.

```html
# Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: rm -r node_modules
2022-08-11T13:02:59.128Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2022-08-11T13:03:05.392Z [INFO]: added 173 packages in 5.946s
```

Here is the amplify.yml

```html
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - rm -r node_modules
        - npm ci
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands:
        - npm start app.js
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference,

I had this issue.
I changed `npm ci` to `npm i` in the amplify build config and it "worked"
I went to my console and tried `npm ci`

> It told me there was a sync problem with the package.json and lock
> file and directed to run `npm install`.

I ran `npm install`
I changed the amplify config to try npm ci for my amplify build again

This time the provision-build-deploy was green

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue.

You should first try executing the exact command on your local computer.
In my case, the consecutive command was showing a prompt and that was why the build process was stuck there forever.

Comment: ok, got you. Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

```html
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

This is the yml file which will lead worked for me in order to build the packages in npm and run in aws amplify.